# What is the captured class of the satisfies method when applied to a list?

Tags: java, assertj

I admit this is a contrived situation, but why does the following code not compile?

Environment details:

- Java: openjdk 11.0.20 2023-07-18
- AssertJ: 3.24.2 (discovered while running 3.21.0)

```java
package example;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

public class ExampleTest {
    public interface ICommon {

    }

    public static class TypeA implements ICommon {
        // assume overridden equals
    }

    public static class TypeB implements ICommon {
        // assume overridden equals
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final List<ICommon> actual = List.of(new TypeA(), new TypeB());
        final List<ICommon> expected = List.of(new TypeA());

        final Iterable<? extends ICommon> thisCompiles = expected; // no problems

        /*
         * 'containsAnyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable<? extends capture<? extends example.ExampleTest.ICommon>>)'
         * in 'org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert' cannot be applied to
         * '(java.util.List<example.ExampleTest.ICommon>)'
         */
        assertThat(actual).satisfies(r -> assertThat(r).containsAnyElementsOf(expected));

        /*
         *
         * 'containsAnyElementsOf(java.lang.Iterable<? extends capture<? extends example.ExampleTest.ICommon>>)'
         * in 'org.assertj.core.api.AbstractIterableAssert' cannot be applied to
         * '(java.lang.Iterable<capture<? extends example.ExampleTest.ICommon>>)'
         */
        assertThat(actual).satisfies(r -> assertThat(r).containsAnyElementsOf(thisCompiles));
    }
}
```

(I Reiterate: this example is not a good way to test what is being tested, it is merely a stripped down model for example purposes only. DO NOT use it as an example of best practices. This is not a place of honor.)

A coworker came to me with code that ultimately boiled down to a similar situation. I managed to give them a better way to do the assertion, but I was personally disturbed because I realized I could not explain *why* this code does not compile. Because of this I am returning to StackOverflow after a long absence to throw this to the community. What is preventing the compiler from figuring this code out?

Comment: Ok, arguing about what I was asking has pushed me a little closer, but I'm not sure I want to edit the original question.  Why does the `ListAssert<ELEMENT>` need to convert into a capture (specifically `? super List<? extends ELEMENT>`) when calling satisfies? What would be the disadvantage of returning `? super List<ELEMENT>`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the `assertThat(assertion)` statement to a typed `ListAssert<ICommon>` variable. This is because the `assertThat` method does not know what the concrete list type should be.

```java
assertThat(actual).satisfies(assertion -> {
    ListAssert<ICommon> list = assertThat(assertion); // Declare the type
    list.containsAnyElementsOf(expected);
});
```

---

Here is a working unit test. I used Lombok to annotate the classes to supply the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. Also, I changed `List.of` to `Arrays.asList` for Java 8 compatibility. Feel free to change it back.

```java
package org.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.assertj.core.api.ListAssert;
import org.junit.Test;

import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

public class ExampleTest {
    public interface ICommon {}

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public static class TypeA implements ICommon {}

    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public static class TypeB implements ICommon {}

    @Test
    public void test() {
        final List<ICommon> actual = Arrays.asList(new TypeA(), new TypeB());
        final List<ICommon> expected = Arrays.asList(new TypeA());

        assertThat(actual).satisfies(assertion -> {
            ListAssert<ICommon> list = assertThat(assertion);
            list.containsAnyElementsOf(expected);
        });
    }
}
```

You could also cast the list inline:

```java
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void test() {
    final List<ICommon> actual = Arrays.asList(new TypeA(), new TypeB());
    final List<ICommon> expected = Arrays.asList(new TypeA());

    assertThat(actual)
        .satisfies(assertion -> ((ListAssert<ICommon>) assertThat(assertion))
            .containsAnyElementsOf(expected));
}
```

Since the `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions#assertThat` method is static, you are required to assign its result into a `ListAssert<ELEMENT>` variables. Where `ELEMENT` is the type of list item to be checked. I believe they thing that is throwing you off is the `<? extends ELEMENT>` part.

```java
/**
 * Creates a new instance of <code>{@link ListAssert}</code>.
 *
 * @param <ELEMENT> the type of elements.
 * @param actual the actual value.
 * @return the created assertion object.
 */
public static <ELEMENT> ListAssert<ELEMENT> assertThat(List<? extends ELEMENT> actual) {
  return AssertionsForInterfaceTypes.assertThat(actual);
}
```

You could simplify this to just:

```java
assertThat(actual).containsAnyElementsOf(expected);
```

Comment: but why? Can you explain what the compiler is getting confused about? Like I said in my question, I know *how* to fix it, but I want to know _why I have to._

Comment: @JonBristow I added an example of the code behind the AssertJ library.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't answer my question... why does it appear that `List<ELEMENT>` is not assignable to `Iterable<? extends ELEMENT>`. what _specifically_ is confusing the compiler.

Comment: my example code contains the assignment from `List` to `Iterable` _and it compiles just fine!_ Where exactly does it break when doing what looks should end up the same type in AssertJ?

Comment: And I understand that `Iterable<? extends capture<? extends example.ExampleTest.ICommon>>` is not _exactly_ the same as `Iterable<capture<? extends example.ExampleTest.ICommon>>` but why not? What is the compiler choking on?

Comment: @JonBristow, calling `assertThat(actual)` already returns a `ListAssert<ICommon>`

Comment: again, I don't want to know HOW to fix it. I want to know what the compiler is doing. How exactly is`Iterable<? extends X>` not equivalent to `Iterable<X>` when `X` is a capture of `<? extends ICommon>`?

Comment: @JonBristow I think this [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/d35ds9/java_generics_addcapture_of_cannot_be_applied_to/ezzcguy/) sums it up. I tailored the wording to **your scenario:** _`List<? extends ELEMENT>` should be read as "a `List` of a specific but unknown type that extends `ELEMENT`", and since that specific but unknown type is not known (it could for example be anything...), you cannot just add `ELEMENT` objects to that list, since the `ELEMENT` is not guaranteed to be of that correct (specific but unknown) type._

Comment: But where is the difference coming from? As you pointed out, assertJ is returning a `ListAssert<ICommon>` so we would expect the `containsAnyElementsOf` to accept a `Iterable<? extends ICommon>`why is `List<ICommon>` not assignable to this?  (And why is the actual type reading as `Iterable<? extends ? extends ICommon>`? And why doesn't ICommon fit the invariant here?)

Comment: @JonBristow AssertJ is only returning a ListAssert<ICommon>, because `assertThat()` behaves differently from an assertion passed in via `satisfies()`. They have different method signatures. When calling `satisfies()`, you need to assign the result to a variable, or else it will not deduce the type correctly.

Comment: Where is the extra capture/question mark coming from, and why is the assertj api written so that this happens? What breaks if we change FactoryBasedNavigableListAssert from `ACTUAL extends List<? extends ELEMENT>` to `ACTUAL extends List<ELEMENT>`?